# React / redux / context : How can I save like for each product in store instead of component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-context

I wonder how I can arrange likes for items in a redux or (in my case context) store. I dont know how I can do it without changing the item (that I receive from backend) in the store (to add a possible like to each item)
So far Im doing the following check inside my component:

```
const SearchResult () => {
const {state: {savedList}} = useContext(SearchContext);
const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
            return savedList.find(item => {
                if (item._id === searchResult._id) setIsLiked(true);
                else setIsiked(false);
            })
        };
    }, []);
...
}
```

**reducer**

```
const likeReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_SAVED_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                savedlist: action.payload
            }
        case 'LIKE_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                savedlist: action.payload //updated list
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**action**

```
const like = dispatch => async (product) => {
    dispatch({type: 'LIKE'})
    try {
       await API.like(product)
        dispatch({type: 'LIKE_SUCCESS', payload: product})
    } catch(error) {
        dispatch({type: 'LIKE_ERROR', payload: error.message})
    }
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you expect?

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear. I want the logic I have in usestate (const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);) to be in my reducer, but dont know how to do it for each item seperatly.

Comment: If you want to update an item in `savedList`, dispatch the action with the target product. Then find it in `savedList` and do an immutable update. See https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if I can do it differently or thats the only way. I am fetching the list from backend, so didnt want to change the items i receive from backend on my client to add to each item like prop.